# The type 'MediaTypeHeaderValue' exists in both 'System.Net.Http"

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

please help,
I am getting following error when I am trying to access API endpoint:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MediaTypeHeaderValue' exists in both 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Looks like you're referencing two different versions of the same library, at a guess.

Comment: uninstalling System.Net.Http and reinstalling it again helped to fix the issue.